# How to send a e-mail for more than one recipient at once, using Delphi and Synapse?

Tags: email, delphi, ararat-synapse

Please, I am trying to solve this "problem" for more than 12 hours now... and almost getting crazy! I think is impossible send the same e-mail for more than a recipient (destination) at once, using Delphi and Synapse (http://synapse.ararat.cz). Please, someone tell me I am wrong :)

Well, I have a sEmail variable, where I get the e-mails separated by point semicolon (;), just like this:

```
sEmails := 'email1@test.com.br;email2@teste.com.br';
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
dSMTP := TSMTPSend.Create;
dSMsg := TMimeMess.Create;
Try 
  With dSMsg, Header Do
  Begin 
    Date := Now;
    Priority := mp_Normal;
    CharsetCode := ISO_8859_1;
    From := 'email@gmail.com';
    ToList.Delimiter := ';';
    ToList.DelimitedText := sEmails;
    Subject := 'Message Subject';
    dPart := AddPartMultipart('mixed', nil);
    AddPartHTML('<h1>Message Text</h1>', dPart);
    EncodeMessage;
  end;
  With dSMTP Do
  Begin
    TargetHost := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    TargetPort := '587';
    AutoTLS := True;
    UserName := 'email@gmail.com';
    Password := 'password';
    Try
      If Login Then
      Begin
        If MailFrom('email@gmail.com', Length('email@gmail.com')) Then
          If MailTo(sEmails) Then MailData(dSMsg.Lines);
        Logout;
      end;
    Except
      On E: Exception Do ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
Finally
  dSMsg.Free;
  dSMTP.Free;
end;
```

I already tried like this:

```
If Login Then
Begin
  If MailFrom('email@gmail.com', Length('email@gmail.com')) Then
    If MailTo(dSMsg.Header.ToList[0]) Then MailData(dSMsg.Lines);
  Logout;
end;
```

... but then only the first e-mail was sent :( Even if add the rest of e-mails in the Header.CCList.

In another test I tried to change point semicolon for comma (,), with same problem...

Please, please, can someone tells what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `SendTo`](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/):

> Send "Maildata" (text of e-mail without any SMTP headers!) from "MailFrom" e-mail address to "MailTo" e-mail address with "Subject". (If you need more then one receiver, then separate their addresses by comma).

So something like this **should** work (but see below, because it doesn't apparently):

```
sEMails := 'joe@gmail.com,fred@gmail.com,mary@gmail.com';
....

if MailTo(sEMails) then 
  MailData(dSMsg.Lines);
```

It seems that there isn't a way to set multiple email addresses properly in the `SMTPSend` component. You have to send each individually. You can, however, do it easier than parsing the addresses yourself, since you've already added them to `dSMsg.Header.ToList` earlier in your code:

```
// Declare i as an integer variable, and post all the send to addresses
// one at a time to the MailTo() function
for i := 0 to dSMsg.Header.ToList.Count - 1 do
   MailTo(dMsg.Header.ToList[i]);

// Now send the mail body
MailData(dSMsg.Lines)
```

IMO, the Synapse SMTP support is too low level to use easily unless you specifically need that low level support for some reason. Both Indy (which comes with Delphi pre-installed) and [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be) provide much easier implementation of `SMTP`, both support both text and HTML emails and MIME-encoded attachments, and both support the TLS needed for working with gmail.

Comment: @SirRufo: I linked to (and quoted) what the Synapse documentation says. If it's wrong, tell Synapse. :-)

Comment: Fortunatelly I got SirRufo tip before was deleted... and it solved the problem! So, please Sir, post it again, to help other people with same problem... Thank you!

Comment: In all Synapse's sendxxxx units, those simple functions like **SentTo** are for simple, quick&dirty purposes and demonstrate how to use core **TXXXXSend** class. Communication software operates with instance of such classes typically (and assumes a basic knowledge of RFC standard behind particular protocol)

Comment: Someone claims my answer to be an "only pasted" one. So I deleted my answer. If there were any helpful parts, they may be included in this answer. I upvoted this one

Comment: Hi Ken. I am new here, but I did not delete your answer (not even by mistake). It helped me to undertand better the way Synapse work, and I am sure it will help more people. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of code how I am sending to multiple recipients.
First you need to setup your TMimeMess (var Mime in this example).

```
uses
  mimemess, smtpsend, mimepart, synautil; //not sure if this list is complete

var 
  SMTP: TSMTPSend;
  s, t: string;
  Mime: TMimeMess;

...

{ log in to SMTP server }
if SMTP.Login then
begin
  { set sender address and total send size }
  if SMTP.MailFrom(synautil.GetEmailAddr({your from address}), 
    Length(Mime.Lines.Text)) then
  begin
    s := {your comma separated e-mail string};

    { add all recipient addresses }
    repeat
      { split addresses by comma and send to each }
      t := synautil.GetEmailAddr(Trim(FetchEx(s, ',', '"')));
      if (t <> '') then
        Result := SMTP.MailTo(t);

      if not Result then
      begin
        //handle failure if necessary here

        Break;
      end;
    until s = '';

    { now send e-mail content }
    if Result then
      Result := SMTP.MailData(Mime.Lines);
  end;

  { and log out }
  SMTP.Logout;
```

Comment: Hi Erik. It is most the same code SirRufo posted yesterday (and deleted). It solved my problem! Thank you!!